# link not working php

Tags: php, html

Here I'm trying to add links to some new pages in php. I'm using php panique for authorization.
[Panique](https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced).

I've added `product-des.php` page in views directory, but when I add anchor tag to link to `product-des.php` from my `index.php` page, the server is getting some 404 not found error. How can I add link in the page without breaking.

Here is how I have added the link in my `index.php` page.

```
<a href="product-des.php?42">jhgjhg</a>
```

what am i doing wrong here? why i am not able to link to the page?

Comment: `<a href="product-des.php?id=42">jhgjhg</a>`

Comment: Are you sure your page is actually there? in the right directory?

Comment: @Dave yes the page is there in views directory... but when i put prod-des.php page in parent directory i am able to see the page working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check there is any page with name `product-des.php` is existing actually or not.

then change link to :- `<a href="product-des.php?id=42">jhgjhg</a>`

and on `product-des.php` page you will get the value through `$_GET['id']`